# Android alarm manager not working on Samsung Galaxy phone

Tags: android

I have created an app which polls a server to fetch SMS that have to be sent to our users. For the polling functionality i have used the alarm manager to fire every 5 min to poll server

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); 
        Intent pintent = new Intent(this, SMSSender.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,pintent, 0);
        if(checkbox.isChecked()) {
            long interval = 60*Integer.valueOf(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("pref_poll_interval", "5000"));//5mins;//5mins
            long firstPoll = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60*Integer.valueOf(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("pref_poll_interval", "5000"));
            alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstPoll, interval, pIntent);
            Log.d("SMS_GATEWAY", "alarm manager turned on "+interval);
        }else {
            alarm.cancel(pIntent);
            Log.d("SMS_GATEWAY", "alarm manager turned off");
        }
```

I have tested the application on the emulator against the 2.2 build and everything works fine, now test the final out of SMS going out i have installed the app on a Samsung Galaxy S phone.

Once the app is installed and the preference to poll server is selected, nothing really happens.

What could be the problem

Comment: I'm having issues (NUMEROUS!) with the Samsung Galaxy S devices.  In this particular case, I'm having issues reading default shared prefs and see the following log message in logcat -- are you seeing this, too?  "W/ApplicationContext( 4563): Attempt to read
preferences file /dbdata/databases/.../
shared_prefs/..._preferences.xml without
permission "

Also, I've found some references to this only being an issue when on 2.2.1 -- what version are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the BuzzBox SDK library for your problem.

http://hub.buzzbox.com/android-sdk/

You can schedule a task using a cron string:

```
SchedulerManager.getInstance()
    .saveTask(this, "*/5 8-19 * * 1,2,3,4,5", YourTask.class);
```

I have a Galaxy S and I'm using the BuzzBox SDK in a few of my apps.
You can check the scheduler log integrated in the SDK to verify that your Task is running properly.

Answer (score 0):

AlarmManager is not working correctly on Samsung phones in deep sleep :( BuzzBox SDK use AlarmManager so it has the same problem (I tested on Galaxy 5500).
For example http://www.netzpurist.de/2010/11/samsung-gt-i5500-with-android-2-1-update1-alarmmanager-not-suitable/